# Today I am trying to run my c++ code but i getting this error

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, launch

[I'm getting this error][1]

Can't find Node.js binary "node": path does not exist. make sure not.js is installed and in your path or set the runtime executable in your launch.json

[my launch.json is ][2]

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting? Paste the code/error and not the image of the code/error.

Comment: C++ is not Node.js. Your launch.json looks like it's set up to do something related to Node, not the C++ code you're trying to compile and run.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: read the C++ doc pages of VSC